# Getting wrong answer in Binary Search solution

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, binary-search, median

## Problem statement

You are given a row-wise sorted matrix `mat` of size `m * n` where `m` and `n` are the numbers of rows and columns of the matrix, respectively.

Your task is to find and return the median of the matrix.

Note: `m` and `n` will always be odd.

Example:

```
Input: n = 5, m = 5
mat = [     
        [ 1, 5, 7, 9, 11 ],
        [ 2, 3, 4, 8, 9 ],
        [ 4, 11, 14, 19, 20 ],
        [ 6, 10, 22, 99, 100 ],
        [ 7, 15, 17, 24, 28 ]   
      ]

Output: 10
```

Explanation: If we arrange the elements of the matrix in the sorted order in an array, they will be like this

```
1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 7 8 9 9 10 11 11 14 15 17 19 20 22 24 28 99 100
```

So the median is `10`, which is at index `12`, which is midway as the total elements are `25`, so the 12th index is exactly midway. Therefore, the answer will be `10`.

This is the question I am trying to solve using Binary Search. Below is the code I have written but it is only able to pass some test cases and showing wrong answer in other cases. I am unable to find if I have made some logical error or my code doesn't work on edge cases.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public final class Solution {
    public static int findMedian(int matrix[][], int m, int n) {
        // Write your code here
        int[] pos= findPos(matrix,m,n);
        int req=(m*n)/2;
        while (pos[0]<=pos[1]) {
            int mid = (pos[0]+pos[1])/2;
            int smallEquals = blackbox(matrix,m,n,mid);
            if(smallEquals>=req){
                pos[1]=mid-1;
            }else{
                pos[0]=mid+1;
            }
        }
        return pos[0];
    }
    public static int blackbox(int matrix[][], int m, int n, int mid){
        int cnt=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            int low=0;
            int high=n-1;
            while(low<=high){
                int mid1=(low+high)/2;
                if(matrix[i][mid1]<mid){
                    low=mid1+1;
                }else{
                    high=mid1-1;
                }
            }
            cnt+=low;
        }
        return cnt;
    }
    public static int[] findPos(int matrix[][], int m, int n){
        int min=matrix[m-1][n-1];
        int max=matrix[0][0];
        for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
            if(matrix[i][0]<min){
                min=matrix[i][0];
            }
            if(matrix[i][n-1]>max){
                max=matrix[i][n-1];
            }
        }
        return new int[]{min,max};
    }
}
```

I have used the optimal solution to solve this problem using Binary Search and Upper Bound. Finding the range of the search space then appying Binary Search on it. However, I am not able to pass all the test cases. The difference is only of 1 between my answer and the correct answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to find the median of a distribution with the binary search. Binary search is an algorithm to find a given element in a sorted set. The median of a distribution is just the value positioned exactly in the middle in a distribution. It just halves a set in a higher and lower set. You just need to get the element in position `arr[length/2]` for distributions with an odd number of elements, while the average between the two middle elements for distributions with an even number of elements, so `(arr[length/2] + arr[length/2+1])/2`.

Comment: Also, you've mentioned tests that are not passed. Could you post them too?

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind your approach? Why do you think your approach should work (letting aside possible issues with the implementaion)

Comment: @dani-vta I am using Binary Search to reduce the time complexity of the algorithm. Rather than creating a sorted 1D array from the given 2D array.

Comment: I am using [this approach](https://takeuforward.org/data-structure/median-of-row-wise-sorted-matrix/) @derpirscher

Comment: @Great412 thanks for the link, that clarifies your intent

Answer (score -2):

import java.util.Arrays;

public final class Solution {

```
public static int findMedian(int[][] matrix, int m, int n) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            min = Math.min(min, matrix[i][j]);
            max = Math.max(max, matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    int left = 0;
    int right = m * n - 1;
    while (left <= right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (countSmallerThan(matrix, m, n, mid) >= (m * n + 1) / 2) {
            right = mid - 1;
        } else {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    return left;
}

private static int countSmallerThan(int[][] matrix, int m, int n, int value) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = n - 1;
        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
            if (matrix[i][mid] < value) {
                count += (high - mid) + 1;
                low = mid + 1;
            } else {
                high = mid - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

}

Comment: This answer would be useful if it had an explanation of what was the problem in the asker's code and why this fixes the issue.

Comment: Still getting wrong answer this is the problem [link](https://www.naukri.com/code360/problems/median-of-a-row-wise-sorted-matrix_1115473?utm_source=striver&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=a_zcoursetuf)

Comment: what are `min` and `max` used for?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For a sorted list, one does not need to search to find the median.  For an odd list of size `n` it is the middle element.  For an even sized list it the average of the middle two elements.  The same notion can be applied (with a little more math) to finding it in an array of sorted rows.